# How to Perform list operation concept in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

In Ruby list concept I try to subtract:

```
["a","b","a","c","c"]--["a","c"] = ["b"]
```

But same i tried in Elixir it return `["a","c","b"]`, in my knowledge mathematically its returns `["b","c"]`

Why elixir behave like that?

Comment: By the way, in which case would you ever get ["b","c"] from that list subtraction?  If you get rid of all of the _"a"_ elements and all of the _"c"_ elements then the result should be ["b"].  Otherwise if you don't get rid of all the _"a"_ elements (or _"c"_) then the result would be dependent on how the developer coded it.

Answer (score 2):

1.) Elixir isn't Ruby.  I can't stress that enough. While it shares syntax, forget your expectations that it should behave the same as Ruby does. By the way, I don't know Ruby but the result you're getting in Ruby seems somewhat odd.

2.) When I try what you asked from iex this is what I get:

```
Interactive Elixir (1.1.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> l1 = ["a","b","a","c","c"]
["a", "b", "a", "c", "c"]
iex(2)> l2 = ["a","c"]
["a", "c"]
iex(3)> l3 = l1 -- l2
["b", "a", "c"]
iex(4)>
```

This is the behavior that I would have expected.  That is, it got rid of one of the `"a"`'s and one of the `"c"`'s. If you're getting a different result then you need to share more details with us: version of Elixir, OS (with version) etc. etc. etc.

Comment: By the way: In Ruby, `["a","b","a","c","c"]-["a","c"]` will return `["b"]`, thus it removes all ocurrences, while Elixir only removes as many ocurrences as are in the right list.

Comment: In Elixir, you can achieve the same with `["a","b","a","c","c"] |> Enum.reject(&Enum.member? ["a","c"], &1)`

Comment: Ah.  Thanks for enlightening me @PatrickOscity. What you're saying about Ruby makes much better sense than what is posted in the question.

Comment: @PatrickOscity you are right ruby returns ["b"] only. Thanks for the comment to how to get result as like ruby. I have a doubt Normally if we subtract two arrays result should return the elements which is present on first array and not present on second array right. This is the common sense right. Can you please explain the Elixir behavior on this.

Comment: A little clarification: first the data structures in question are lists, not arrays. I know that may seem like a trivial detail but I've found in software development it's often wise to watch the details. Second, why would it be any more "common sense" for a list subtraction to behave the way you detailed than any other way? What may seem common sense to some may seem quite mystifying to others. It's often down to relatively arbitrary choices.